# Spray-painting polystyrene for outdoor use

Tags: painting

I want to make false stone looking planters from polystyrene heads. I bought the stone spray paint to use, but reading the instructions it says it's for indoor use only! I want to put my heads outside, what other type of product can I use on them?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, using regular spray paint on polystyrene will melt the material, damaging it significantly!

So, before anything else, I'd suggest either coating your polystyrene head, or using a polystyrene-safe spray paint.

- To coat the polystyrene object, use gesso (or another acrylic primer), plaster, a polystyrene-safe primer spray paint, or even white glue.
- Now you can safely apply the fake stone layer. **You can opt for a spray paint that's suitable for outdoor use, or use your current spray paint, and coat it afterwards.**
- After the recommended amount of drying time, you can protect your creation with, for example, a clear acrylic coating spray.

Comment: I was wondering if you've done this before, will it still look like stone with a clear protective coating?

Comment: I have not done this before, no, but I think that will depend mostly on the finish, whether it's matte or glossy. You can also add a little texture to the polystyrene with gesso, so it won't look as polished once the coating is applied.